# Can I backup or restore my old PS3 hard drive to a new PS3?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

My PS3 just YLOD'd. I'm hoping its just a temporary overheating issue and if I just leave it off and unplugged for the day I can get it back on long enough to eject the game disc and backup the hard drive.

From reading up on the YLOD, it sounds like this a sign that if it's not dead already it will be dead in the near future; so I've resigned myself to just buying a new PS3. My question is this:

Can I...

1. Backup my old PS3 hard drive to an external hardrive
2. Move the old hard drive from my 60gb PS3 (I upgraded the drive to a 640gb drive a while ago) to a PS3 slim. I know that once I insert the drive it will prompt me to reformat the drive; this should be fine since I backed up my data first.
3. Restore my backup on the new PS3 and get back most of my saved data? I know some games encrypt their save data, so I might be screwed with certain games.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes, you can backup the drive**, assuming you can get it to bootup and run without getting the yellow light.  [Sony's User Guide on backing up states:](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/backuputility.html).

> Some types of backed up data can be restored on another PS3™ system. The types of data that can be restored on another system are as follows:
>
> - Saved data from PlayStation®3 format software *1
>
>   Image files under  (Photo)
>
>   Music files under  (Music) *2
>
>   Video files under  (Video) *2
>
>   Bookmarks added under  (Internet Browser)
>
>   Terms that were added using  (Settings) >  (System Settings) > [Add/Edit Term], or predictive terms that were "learned" by the on-screen keyboard
>
> *1     Copy-protected data cannot be restored. Also, saved data that has been restored may not be usable in some games.
>
> *2     Does not include copyright-protected data.

Most everything should backup and restore, **except copy-protectd game saves, movies, and music.**

Your best bet for getting your data to the new system is to  **transfer the data directly from the old to the new PS3** using an ethernet cable.  Again, [details in the PS3 User Guide](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/settings/transferutility.html).  Unfortunately, both systems have to be functional for this to work.  After the transfer, any old backups will no longer work.  From the user guide:

> If you back up data on a PS3™ system and then transfer data to another PS3™ system using the data transfer utility, copy-prohibited saved data that is included in the backup data cannot be restored on either system.

Unfortunately, **you can't just swap hard drives between systems**.  According to [this thread requesting this feature](http://share.blog.us.playstation.com/ideas/2010/03/18/hard-drive-transfer-feature/), it looks like the PS3 encrypts the internal drive with a key that is unique to each physical system.  This key can't be transferred.

Good luck!

Comment: Are there any options available when your old PS3 won't boot?  I assume not seeing as the contents of the drive is encrypted.

Answer (score -1):

Two ways to do this:

- Backup the whole disk with the system, registry and drivers and your games to an external hard drive, and restore the image to the new hard disk.
- Just directly clone the old hard drive to the new one with everything on it.  You may also resize the partitions on the new disk.

Here's the way in which I [upgraded my hard drive](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/features/disk-clone-guide.htm) without reinstalling the system.

Comment: This sounds like an answer for PC, not PS3.

Comment: You can in fact do this with a PS3 drive (using a PC/laptop) and it works, but it doesn't resize the disk, and it won't allow transfer to a new machine.