# Backup and reassign of protected save games from on PS3 HDD to another

Tags: ps3

My PS3 died with YLOD two days ago. I haven't been able to power it on since.

I'd like to be able to backup and reassign the saved games, including the protected saves, to a new PS3's HDD.

Is there any software available which can, via a PC, extract saved game data from a PS3 hard disk and reassign it to a different PS3 hard disk?

Comment: Postscript: It's looking like my best bet is to attempt repair myself, then immediately sign up to Playstation Plus and upload my saves to the cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think you're out of luck.**  As another answer states, you can only restore encrypted game saves to the same physical PS3.  **See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16395/backup-restore-old-ps3-hard-drive-to-new-ps3/16406#16406) for more details** (including a number you can use to call Sony about repair).

**If you were a member of [PlayStation Plus](http://us.playstation.com/psn/playstation-plus/), it would allow you to store up to <strike>150 MB</strike> 1Gb of game saves on Sony's servers**, which would be accessible via your PSN ID.  However, this doesn't really help you since your console is dead.

Comment: yup, i really hate these annoyances that we have come to be ok with in gaming. I can't imagine a PC game being able to pull this crap. they tried DRM and all the online blah in ac2/spore and look how they failed.

Comment: I thought this was the case. But I'm not up on what's happening in the PS3 Jailbreak scene, so I thought the question was worth asking.

Comment: yeah.. i was just ranting. It is good question and I am sure others people have experience similar problems. What I hate is that all my hard work is just sitting there and I can do nothing because of some dumb 'policy'

Answer (score 0):

So officially, if you have backed up your data from the ps3 ( using the backup utility ) then you can restore it to the same ps3. The protected save files are signed with the unique id of the ps3.

Now, if your ps3 was working, you could have used the Data transfer utility to transfer the saved files to another ps3 via Ethernet, but since that is not possible, I am afraid there is no way to get the files from the ps3.

Comment: Interesting link. The method used relies on being able to access the PS3 by having an FTP server installed - ie. the PS3 has to be working and jailbroken. Or am I missing something?

Comment: hmm... the data files can be read in 'other' ways. I would suggest looking for stuff like http://www.ps3news.com/PS3HDD/PS3_Hard_Drive_Map_Unveiled/

Comment: The link is now dead.  Is there something else that users can use to fix the save games?