# Is a PS3 backup transferable between hard drives?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What data does the PS3’s backup utility preserve?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23976/what-data-does-the-ps3s-backup-utility-preserve)

I have a 2.5" HDD I'm going to replace in my PSE, but I do not have a spare hard drive I can use as to backup the PS3 to and restore to the new drive.

I was thinking I could use the hard drive I'm going to put in the PS3 as a temporary backup drive, transfer the files onto my computer and then put that drive into the PS3. After that I can mount the old ps3 hard drive into the external enclosure, format it and then transfer the backup data onto the now external old-PS3 hard drive and restore backup data like normal. Is this process possible?

The reason why I want to do this is because most of my current games are downloaded from the PS Store and I don't want to have to go through the process of downloading them all again...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to move PS3 backup between drives, so the process you're trying is possible.

However, since the PS3 backup process tends to mess up sometimes (personal experience), I would recommend you don't format your old PS3 HDD until after you've finished the backup restore into the new drive and make sure everything is in its place and not missing, therefore I recommend you don't use the old HDD for your process unless you're really need to, and if you do, create a disk image of it before you format, just in case.

Comment: I don't believe you can create a disk image of a PS3 drive as it is encrypted. That may perhaps only limit access to the drives contents but worth being aware of.

Comment: I think a bit-for-bit backup is possible, even if you cant decrypt the contents of the HDD itself. It'll probably be only recoverable to the same drive.

Comment: Certainly worth a test. A bit-for-bit backup should work though to the same hard drive as you suggest.